# How to search for block of text using regex search in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I do a search with regex if I'm looking for a text block with line breaks?

Ej:

```
import re

t= '''  #ven=W_insert()
    #ven.play()
    xxxxxxxf
    zacku'''

x= '''  #ven=W_insert()
    #ven.play()
    xxxxxxxf
    zacku'''

print(re.search(x,t))
```

when I try to do it the result I get is 'none'.

I need to locate a block of text within a very large text. That is why x == t does not work for this case

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that doesn't work has nothing to do with multiline strings.  `(` and `)` are special characters in regex patterns, which are used to denote capture groups, that's why your search fails.

If you need to search for a pattern with literal `(` or `)` you can always escape them with backslashes `\` (I also used a raw-string literal here, as is preferable with regex patterns):

```
import re

t = '''  #ven=W_insert()
    #ven.play()
    xxxxxxxf
    zacku'''

x = r'''  #ven=W_insert\(\)
    #ven.play\(\)
    xxxxxxxf
    zacku'''    

print(re.search(x, t))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 56), match='  #ven=W_insert()\n    #ven.play()\n    xxxxxxxf\>
> ```

You can also use `re.escape` to do the escaping automatically:

```
import re

t = '''  #ven=W_insert()
    #ven.play()
    xxxxxxxf
    zacku'''

x = '''  #ven=W_insert()
    #ven.play()
    xxxxxxxf
    zacku'''    

print(re.search(re.escape(x), t))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 56), match='  #ven=W_insert()\n    #ven.play()\n    xxxxxxxf\>
> ```